# Excel vba Error 1004 trying to output array of data onto a sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am copying in data from a range on one sheet, assigning it to an array, then looping through the array and trying to output the data onto another sheet. I keep getting error 1004: Application defined or object defined error.

```
Worksheets("tempSort").Activate

With Application.Worksheets("tempSort")
    .Range("A1:B" & EndRowDummy).Sort key1:=Range("B1:B" & EndRowDummy), _
    order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo
End With

i = 1
y = i + 1

Call ClearSortedResultsSheet
Call PrintSortedResultsHeaders

For i = 1 To EndRowDummy    
    x = Sheets("tempSort").Range("A" & i).text
    Worksheets("Sorted Results").Range("A" & y) = x
    playerData = Sheets(x).Range("C2:F2").Value
    b = 2

    For Each data In playerData
        Worksheets("Sorted Results").Cells(y, b) = data
        b = b + 1
    Next data
Next i
```

It throws the error in the `For Each` loop.

Comment: IF the error is really in the `For Each` and not before, difficult to see the error's reason from the piece of code you've shown, as long as you don't use the `Option Explicit`. First step to narrow down the search is to set this option and `Dim` your variables, hopefully something wrong will be spotted. Also, check your `"Sorted Results"` worksheet, does it have some cells with `Data Validation`?

Comment: Let me try running it first

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get an error when I ran your code. Understand though that I commented out the two calls because I don't have those subroutines.

```
Call ClearSortedResultsSheet
Call PrintSortedResultsHeaders
```

And I also was getting all the results on row 2 of the Worksheets("Sorted Results") sheet.  So I added a y = y + 1 line to write them on separate rows.

Other than that I would search for any changes that ClearSortedResultsSheet or PrintSortedResultsHeaders might have made to cause the error.  Perhaps they changed the active sheet or something.

Here is your code that worked fine on my computer with only an added dim and y = y + 1 statement.

```
Sub test()
Dim playerData() As Variant

        Worksheets("tempSort").Activate ' copy this and place it below the subroutine calls
        EndRowDummy = 3

        With Application.Worksheets("tempSort")
            .Range("A1:B" & EndRowDummy).Sort key1:=Range("B1:B" & EndRowDummy), _
            order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo
        End With

        i = 1
        y = i + 1


        'Call ClearSortedResultsSheet
        'Call PrintSortedResultsHeaders
        Worksheets("tempSort").Activate '    in case the subroutine changed the activesheet
        For i = 1 To EndRowDummy
            x = Sheets("tempSort").Range("A" & i).Text
            Worksheets("Sorted Results").Range("A" & y) = x
            abc = Sheets(x).Range("C2").Value
            playerData = Sheets(x).Range("C2:F2").Value
        '    abc = playerData(1)
            b = 2

            For Each Data In playerData
                Worksheets("Sorted Results").Cells(y, b) = Data
                b = b + 1
            Next Data
            y = y + 1
        Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: I had the y = y+1 in the original. The code I posted was a snippet; I didn't quite copy/paste correctly. I didn't want to post the entire code because it was quite long.

You mention the Worksheets("tempSort").Activate. Should it matter what the active sheet is for this code to run cleanly?

Comment: Not necessarily with your code because you are pretty good about naming your worksheets.  I renamed my worksheets the same as yours, and like I said, the above code ran flawlessly without the calls to those two other subroutines.  I didn't get the error.  I was only suggesting that something one of those two subroutines does is causing the error because I didn't run the subroutines and didn't get the error.  Activesheet was just a guess.